# GROUP_CONCAT trazendo resposta incompleta

Tags: mysql, concatenação-de-string, group-concat

Estou tentando trazer todos os nomes de produtos (mesmo os repetidos) que tenho cadastrados em uma planilha, mas o código está parando no meio do processo. Alguém sabe me dizer o porquê ? Será que existe um limite de caracteres que ao ser atingido no `GROUP_CONCAT` a query é interrompida ?

Estou adicionando um `'\n'` para que na string cada final de nome tenha uma quebra de linha.

meu db é relacional por isso preciso fazer um caminho até conseguir a descricao o item. Segue:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(desc.nome_produto separator '\n')
FROM
  tb_cadastro_itens itens
INNER JOIN 
  tb_cadastro_raiz root
ON 
  root.id = itens.id_item_cadastro
INNER JOIN 
  subtb_cadastro_descricao desc
ON
  desc.id = root.id_desc
WHERE itens.prateleira = 3
```

Comment: tente alterar  para isso `(desc.nome_produto,  '\n');`

Comment: @Mateus estranho cara, dessa maneira muda um pouco o resultado mas ainda está longe do fim correto do resultado. Eu creio que seja algo quantidade de caracteres pois nao importa a condição que eu coloque o resultado para em torno de 900 caracteres.

Comment: o resultado para inclusive no meio de um palavra deixando ela incompleta, por ex: o que seria 'MARTELO' para no 'MART'

Comment: Da uma olhada sobre o `LIMIT SQL` . E vê se não tem algo com seu `WHERE`?

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, realmente é um problema de GROUP_CONCAT() maximum length, consegui resolver isso fazendo um SET assim: SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000 ... porém é uma solução temporária que terá que ser reperida todas as vezes que chamar um GROUP_CONCAT grande. De qualquer forma obrigado pela ajuda @Mateus

Comment: Entendi. De nada.